# Class decorator, how to make sure the class is extending and implementing other classes

Tags: class, typescript, extends, implements

Sorry for the weird title, I don't quite know how to describe what I'm trying to do in one sentence.

I have to define a bunch of classes that are all going to extend from this one class and also implement this other class.

```
class SoulCoughing extends Super implements BonBon { /.../ }
class MoveAside extends Super implements BonBon { /.../ }
class LetTheManGoThru extends Super implements BonBon { /.../ }
```

I have written a sort of wrapper function that I use as a decorator for these classes.

```
const Eminem = function(klass: Constructable<????>) {
  const instance = new klass();
  // Do stuff
}
```

`Constructable` is a little interface I'm using because otherwise TypeScript would throw an error about not having a constructor.

```
interface Constructable<T> {
  new(): T;
}
```

Now here is my problem, I don't know what type to assign to parameter `klass` in my wrapper function? I have tried doing this:

```
... function(klass: Contrusctable<Super & BonBon>)
```

and this:

```
... function(klass: Contrusctable<Super | BonBon>)
```

I also tried modifying my constructable interface like this:

```
interface Constructable<T, U> {
  new(): T & U;
}

... function(klass: Contrusctable<Super, BonBon>)
```

but I keep getting an `Argument of type 'typeof SoulCoughing' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructable<everythingIveTriedSoFar>'` error.

So my question is, what type definition should I use with the parameter `klass`? I know I can just use `any` but I'd really like to make sure that the class being passed has extended `Super` and implemented `BonBon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the classes `SoulCoughing` etc. don't actually have no-arg constructors, and therefore cannot act as `Constructable<{}>` at all;  the most likely culprit is that `Super`'s constructor has a mandatory argument, which would make all subclasses fail to match `new()` by default.  Note that this also implies that your implementation of `Eminem` probably wants to call `new klass(...)` with some arguments also.

The right way to fix it is to declare `Constructable<T>` to be a constructor with the right argument types.  Let's say `Super` looks like this:

```
class Super {
  constructor(elevator: number, mezzanine: string) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Then you could define `Constructable` to match:

```
interface Constructable<T extends Super & BonBon = Super & BonBon> {
  new(chump: number, change: string): T; // same args as Super
}
```

and `Eminem` like:

```
const Eminem = function(klass: Constructable) {
  const instance = new klass(2, "rise");
  // Do stuff
}
```

and finally:

```
Eminem(SoulCoughing); // no error
```

I only kept `Constructable` generic in case you wanted TypeScript to preserve the type of the particular subclass, like so:

```
const SlimShady = function <T extends Super & BonBon>(klass: Constructable<T>): T {
  return new klass(2, "fat");
}

// returns same type as passed-in constructor
const cutLean: MoveAside = SlimShady(MoveAside);
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!